# Verificação de um array, e substituição de seu valor (JS)

Tags: javascript, array

Estou desenvolvendo um simples jogo de campo minado, porém estou encontrando dificuldade para concertar um pequeno bug.

As minas do campo são geradas aleatóriamente através da função a seguir:

```
function randomMines (quantity, rows, cols) {
var mine = [];
for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++){
    var posRow = parseInt(Math.random() * rows);
    var posCol = parseInt(Math.random() * cols); 
    mine.push([posRow, posCol]);
    mine.sort();
}
return mine;   }
```

Porém, eventualmente, uma mina será gerada com as mesmas orientações (rows/cols) de uma já existente dentro do array, fazendo com que aó invés de renderizar 10 minas, ele renderize 9.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que no index 8 e 9, são as mesmas cordenadas.

Como posso fazer para comparar os valores de dentro do array, e caso ele encontro um valor que seja igual a um já existente, ele substitua o mesmo?

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
function randomMines (quantity, rows, cols) {
    var mine = [];
    while(mine.length < quantity){
        var posRow = parseInt(Math.random() * rows);
        var posCol = parseInt(Math.random() * cols); 
        if(mine.filter(item => { return item[0] === posRow && item[1] === posCol;}).length > 0){
            continue;
        }
        
        mine.push([posRow, posCol]);
        mine.sort();
    }
    return mine;   
}
var arr = randomMines(10,10,10);
console.log(arr);
```